# My id value not read number 0 from the first number after passing to other blade

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I try to passing id value to my other blade and its worked but the other blade file didnt read number of 0 at the first number . Example when i passing value of 006 then when i console log the value from the other blade view its only show 6.

my onclick which is value was passed

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-default pull-right" type="button" title="Search Branch" onclick="openNewWindow('{{ route('reporting.branchCheckBoxList', ['cuid' => '_cuid_', 'stid' => '_stid_']) }}'.replace('_cuid_', document.getElementById('cu').value).replace('_stid_', document.getElementById('state').value))" ><i class="fa fa-hand-o-up">
```

web route

```
Route::get('reporting/branchCheckBoxList/{cuid}/{stid?}','GenReportController@branchCheckBoxList')->name('reporting.branchCheckBoxList');
```

my controller

```
    public function branchCheckBoxList($cuid, $stid ) {

    $cuid = $cuid;
    $stid = $stid;

    return view('report.BranchCheckBoxList',  compact('cuid','stid'));
}
```

my other blade view

```
<script>
var cuid = {{ $cuid }} ;
console.log(cuid); //my console only read 6 if i pass 006 
</script>
```

i need to fix my value which is can return with the read number 0 at first number sorry for my bad english

Comment: Could you maybe do the following `{{ dd('$cuid') }}`

Comment: hi sir...{{ dd('$cuid') }} put in my script ??

Comment: Dont put it in your script. Place it above the script and return the output

Comment: it shows it return 006

Comment: console.log is not showing the leading zero's so when you're trying to log it you lose the leading numbers

Comment: yes sir.....any idea sir? hope u can help me

Comment: Check my awnser below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already solved the answer which is put " " for my var cuid

```
var cuid = " {{ $cuid }} "
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not showing you the leading zero's, when you use the laravel dd function the output is 006 but the console.log function strips the leading zero's.

If you want the leading zero's to show up you have to format it to a string.

```
<script>
    var cuid = "{{$cuid}}";
    console.log(cuid);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks you for your feedback sir but i already solve by putting "  " for my cuid like this var cuid = " {{ $cuid }} "